Transform columns in rows in linux shell
I have this file:
192.168.0.35 GigabitEthernet0/19 AP-CISCO-02
192.168.0.35 GigabitEthernet0/20 AP-CISCO-12
192.168.0.36 GigabitEthernet0/12 AP-CISCO-70
192.168.0.36 GigabitEthernet0/20 AP-CISCO-71
192.168.0.40 GigabitEthernet1/0/22 AP-CISCO-73
192.168.0.254 GigabitEthernet2/47 AP-CISCO-19
192.168.0.254 GigabitEthernet3/37 AP-CISCO-86
192.168.0.254 GigabitEthernet3/38 AP-CISCO-85

I need to transform it to a CSV that should look like this:
192.168.0.35, 192.168.0.36, 192.168.0.40, 192.168.0.254
"GigabitEthernet0/19, GigabitEthernet0/20", "GigabitEthernet0/12, GigabitEthernet0/20", "GigabitEthernet1/0/22", "GigabitEthernet2/47, GigabitEthernet3/37, GigabitEthernet3/38"
"AP-CISCO-02, AP-CISCO-12", "AP-CISCO-70, AP-CISCO-71", "AP-CISCO-73", "AP-CISCO-19, AP-CISCO-86, AP-CISCO-85"

It shoudld transform the columns in to rows and group the columns of the resulting file according to the first row.
The first row should be the switches ips, the second row should be their respective interfaces and the third their descriptions.
I tried this:
awk '{
    for (f = 1; f <= NF; f++) {
        a[NR, f] = $f 
    } 
}

NF > nf { nf = NF }

END {
   for (f = 1; f <= nf; f++) {
       for (r = 1; r <= NR; r++) {
           printf "\""a[r, f]"\"" (r==NR ? RS : FS=",")
       }
   }
}' myfile

But the output is this:
"192.168.0.35","192.168.0.35","192.168.0.36","192.168.0.36","192.168.0.40","192.168.0.254","192.168.0.254","192.168.0.254"
"GigabitEthernet0/19","GigabitEthernet0/20","GigabitEthernet0/12","GigabitEthernet0/20","GigabitEthernet1/0/22","GigabitEthernet2/47","GigabitEthernet3/37","GigabitEthernet3/38"
"AP-CISCO-02","AP-CISCO-12","AP-CISCO-70","AP-CISCO-71","AP-CISCO-73","AP-CISCO-19","AP-CISCO-86","AP-CISCO-85"

This is not what I need. The switches address shouldnt repeat, they shoud be a single entry in the csv. And the switches interfaces should be grouped too, for example: 192.168.0.254 has three interfaces so it should be like "GigabitEthernet2/47, GigabitEthernet3/37, GigabitEthernet3/38" in the csv.
EDIT:
I have managed to achieve exactly what I need with awk. Will add the answer if anyone ever need this. If anyone has a better answer I will like it too. Thanks.
{
    for (f = 1; f <= NF; f++) {
        a[NR, f] = $f 
    } 
}

NF > nf { nf = NF }

END {
 intlist="\""
 desclist="\""
 for (f = 1; f <= nf; f++) {
       for (r = 1; r <= NR; r++) {
           if (f==1) {
                if (a[r,1]!=a[r+1,1]) {
                    printf a[r,f] (r==NR ? RS="\n" : FS=",")
                }
           }
           
           if (f==2){
                if (r==1){
                    intlist=intlist""a[r,2]
                }
                else{
                    if (a[r,1]==a[r-1,1]) {
                        intlist=intlist", "a[r,2]
                    }
                    else {
                        printf intlist"\","
                        intlist="\""a[r,2] 
                    }
                }
                
                if (r==NR) {
                   printf intlist"\"\n"
                }
           }
           
           if (f==3){
                if (r==1){
                    desclist=desclist""a[r,3]
                }
                else{
                    if (a[r,1]==a[r-1,1]) {
                        desclist=desclist", "a[r,3]
                    }
                    else {
                        printf desclist"\","
                        desclist="\""a[r,3] 
                    }
                }
                
                if (r==NR) {
                   printf desclist"\""
                }
           }
       }
   }
}


You've told us your objective, but you haven't shown us your attempt or explained what problem or error you encountered with that attempt.  Please edit your question and show us what you tried and provide more details about how that attempt didn't meet your objective.

It would help if you would show how the file is broken up into individual lines. Or does each file really consist of a single line only?

You objective file is not a valid csv tho. Are you sure that you should not be separating columns of the 2nd and 3rd row that belongs to the same IP with something else than a coma? A csv is supposed to have the same number of fields (hence of comas, unless between quotes) in each row (see RFC 4180, 2.4 : « Each line should contain the same number of fields throughout the file »). There is no "colspan" in csv to have a header cover more than 1 column. So congrat if you've managed to do what you wanted. But what you wanted is by definition not a CSV.

Your original file is a space-separated file. To convert it to a comma-separated file, in a text editor find-replace all the spaces with comma (I am assuming there are no spaces in the data values). (optional) Write the header of the CSV file in the first row.
This is a typical CSV file format-
IP,interface,description,
92.168.0.35,GigabitEthernet0/19,AP-CISCO-02
192.168.0.35,GigabitEthernet0/20,AP-CISCO-12
etc...

Write a script to store three lists in memory-

a list of ip address ranges
a list of interface names
a list of descriptions

A read loop that stops at each item (stop at the separator symbol) will append one ip address range, one interface name, and one description. Read loop should run until the end of file is reached.
Now that reading is done, begin writing to a file.

Write the list of ip address ranges. Write a comma after each. Write a newline at the end of the list.
Write the list of interfaces. Write a comma after each. Write a newline at the end of the list.
Write the list of descriptions. Write a comma after each. Write a newline at the end of the list.

192.168.0.35, 192.168.0.36, 192.168.0.40, 192.168.0.254
GigabitEthernet0/19, GigabitEthernet0/20, GigabitEthernet0/12, GigabitEthernet0/20, GigabitEthernet1/0/22, GigabitEthernet2/47, GigabitEthernet3/37, GigabitEthernet3/38
AP-CISCO-02, AP-CISCO-12, AP-CISCO-70, AP-CISCO-71, AP-CISCO-73, AP-CISCO-19, AP-CISCO-86, AP-CISCO-85

Just be aware that the final file is not a typical CSV file format.

I already achieved this but this is not what I need. Your solution would work if each switch had only one interface. But if you look carefully 192.168.0.254 has three interfaces so these interfaces should be grouped in a single entry in the csv.
